# Strange folder name coming in qt makefile

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I have a makefile.qt file, and whenever I make it, there are unknown folders generated.
Makefile.qt:

```
include buildconfig
%.mak : %.pro qtconfig
    $(MAYA_LOCATION)/bin/$(QMAKE) -o - QMAKE_CC=$(CC) QMAKE_CXX=$(C++) $< | \
        LC_CTYPE=C sed -e '/^TARGET.*=/s?=.*$$?= $$(QMAKE_TARGET).$(EXT)?' \
            -e 's?-framework QtCore?$$(MAYA_LOCATION)/MacOS/QtCore?' \
            -e 's?-framework QtGui?$$(MAYA_LOCATION)/MacOS/QtGui?' \
            -e 's?-framework QtOpenGL?$$(MAYA_LOCATION)/MacOS/QtOpenGL?' \
            -e 's?-framework QtTest?$$(MAYA_LOCATION)/MacOS/QtTest?' \
            -e 's?-framework QtXml?$$(MAYA_LOCATION)/MacOS/QtXml?' \
            -e 's?-framework Maya?$$(MAYA_LOCATION)/MacOS/Maya?' \
            -e 's?-dynamiclib??' -e 's?-mtune=generic??' >$@

PLUGINS =   helixQtCmd.$(EXT)

ifeq ($(QMAKE),)
all:
    @echo "Qt not found. Qt-based plug-ins will not be built."
else
all:    $(PLUGINS)
endif


# For each plugin, make sure that its individual Makefile is up-to-date then
# use that Makefile to build the plugin.
.PHONY: force
%.$(EXT):   force

    $(MAKE) -f Makefile.qt $(@:.$(EXT)=.mak)
    $(MAKE) -f $(@:.$(EXT)=.mak) $@
    cp $(@:.$(EXT)=.bundle) compiled_plugins/maya$(MAYA_VERSION)/plug-ins/Plurii.bundle

clean:
    rm -f $(PLUGINS:.$(EXT)=.o) $(PLUGINS:.$(EXT)=.mak) \
        moc_output/* ui_* qrc_* *.o

Clean:  clean
    rm -f $(PLUGINS)
```

In order to build my plugin, I use the following command:

```
make -f Makefile.qt <myplugin>.bundle
```

However this generates a .mak file in which there are plenty of Include and Lib folders that are incorrect and I can't find where they are coming from:

```
-I/Users/caiwe/qt/qt-4.8.6/include/QtGui
-L/Users/caiwe/qt/qt-4.8.6/lib
/Users/caiwe/qt/qt-4.8.6/bin/moc
...
```

I have no clue where these /Users/caiwe come from, as this is not me. Any hint where I can find this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was coming from the mkspecs folder which I took from maya2016 download. Taking the mkspecs folder which was provided with maya2015 made it work.